# Train scheduled to leave Russia before visa expiry but is delayed - what happens?

Tags: visas, trains, russia, delays, moldova

So my friend is going to Russia, and has booked the train ticket from Finland to St Petersburg (for those following [my earlier question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71950/is-it-possible-to-enter-russia-by-train-1-1-5-hours-before-the-visa-validity-per), I convinced her NOT to enter Russia a day earlier).

However, there's the still the Train from Russia to Moldova, which leaves Russia around 23:00 (at Bryansk).

My question is: what would happen at the border if a Train **is scheduled** to leave Russia while the visa's valid according to the timetable, but is delayed?

This is important because it'll decide whether she'll Exit a day earlier or not.

Comment: Your friend is responsible for adhering to visa rules, short of a natural disaster. A delayed train is not an excuse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This situation is hard to answer, as the trains has much more stable schedule rather than planes, so there are no such situations I can find about Russian railways. This could be two ways - the border officers would have a previous date stamps or not. If the train would be delayed and dates switched, your friend still has a trouble. But, again, this situation is no so probable as the trains in Moldova haven't been delayed recently.

However, in 2014 there was an accident on this train ([link in Russian](http://www.vesti.ru/doc.html?id=1604829&tid=106834)) and it has been delayed for a 6 hours. After that, before the accident results were fixed, trains were delayed up to 4 hours ([link in Russian](http://www.m24.ru/articles/45249)) on this route.

So, if your friend feels unlucky, she can use other options, but I think this is safe for she to use this train, as in case of emergency it will be easier to explain the visa date expiration.