# Should I say hello to the passport control officers, or just quietly give them my passport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, etiquette, officials

What is the etiquette? What do the passport control officers expect? I’m asking from the point of politeness and efficiency.

Comment: Conventions in such official interactions depends on the culture. Passport officials tend to see people from many different cultures, so I doubt they really care. That said, better to err on the side of being extra polite (albeit not too chatty).

Comment: Especially if it's not busy, I'll make small talk with Canadian and US border officers, and UK ones seem willing to make a little small talk too (although I've never seen one that wasn't super busy).  On the other hand, when I've seen border officers in Germany, Switzerland and France, none of them ever said even a word to me.

Comment: Avoid muttering under your breath and saying words like bomb :)

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72306/in-what-language-should-i-address-foreign-customs-and-immigration

Comment: I've noticed that immigration officials tend to ask certain questions and expect certain answers (or maybe more accurately, certain *kinds* of answers) depending on the background the traveler is claiming to have. They even read body language and other signs that are typical of some groups. It's really interesting to see.

Comment: As a personal anecdote, I arrived at Heathrow on July 4th this year. Upon presenting our US passports to the IO, _he_ initiated the conversation with a joke about US Independence. We had a casual conversation as he did what he needed to do, then we were on our way with "have a great days" all around.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Saying hello indicates you speak at least some English, which avoids the need for the immigration officer to ask.
They may be interested in your accent - if you have a characteristic accent from some part of the country you're visiting, but have not lived in that country, they may be suspicious. The same could apply if you try to speak a little of the local language that is not normally learned by tourists. In the pre-Schengen days, a German friend who had taught himself some Danish was treated with suspicion at the Danish border as they suspected him of living there without being documented.

As a Scot, I find it useful to exaggerate my Scottish accent at US immigration.

Comment: I am curious about the last sentence.  Why is that so?

Comment: I have had some great conversations with US passport control agents when they read my last name (it's Irish) and we talk about Irish heritage. It's a nice change to the typical "confrontational" atmosphere you can sometimes get from them. e.g. passport controller: "Oh, my grandfather was Irish too!" - taps badge, it says "O'Neill".

Comment: I'm not sure the OP is asking necessarily about saying "hello" in an English-speaking country (there's no mention of a country in the question), so I think this answer would benefit from being generalized to greeting in the language(s) of the destination question.

Comment: " if you have a characteristic accent from some part of the country you're visiting, but have not lived in that country" - that covers just about everyone I ever worked with in Holland or Scandinavia. There's something weird about a Norwegian with a fluent Brummie or Mancunian accent :-)

Comment: I'm Swedish (with the corresponding ID/passport) but look Yugoslav/Bulgarian and speak English and German with near-native accents (southern English and northern German respectively). This alone has never caused any suspicion in the UK, US, Germany or Switzerland (where I live), other than once at Gatwick, where the officer clearly thought my ID was fake, leading me to present my (non-photographic) debit card as well

Answer (score 118):

I’m a former Immigration Officer myself (in the UK).

Saying “hello” (or “good morning/evening” etc) is entirely appropriate, just like any other encounter in the English-speaking world. It distinguishes us from machines, acknowledging the human interaction. In other words, if you did not greet the officer then you may as well be using one of the automated passport gates.

You will frequently find the officer initiating the contact anyway. If the officer greets you, make sure to greet them back - otherwise you will appear rude. It’s just like any other human encounter.

I agree with what others have said though: beyond the initial greeting, don’t bother to engage in small talk (“how are you today?”), when the queue is long. Just say hello while handing over your passport, and thereafter answer any questions.

We also appreciate it if the passport is passed already open at the bio-data (photo) page for EEA/Swiss nationals; or if you’re a visa national, with the relevant visa page already open.

Comment: Coke - while I appreciate your edit, it's not quite right. Non-visa nationals do not belong in that EEA/Swiss list, because the EEA/Swiss documents will (usually) *only* have their bio-data pages examined, and the queue is fast-moving, so officers just want to examine the relevant pages without delay. On the other hand, non-visa nationals' passports require examination of the whole document in all cases, and the queue is a lot slower moving. The couple of seconds gained by having the bio-data page open is slightly appreciated, but practically neither here nor there :)

Comment: Hrm, at STN (where I enter regularly) and St Pancras (arriving on the Eurostar from Marne-la-Vallée) I often join the non-EEA queue (it's often quicker and sometimes even empty) and sometimes take a sneak peek at others being processed. Per my observations, US, Canadian and Australian passports at least often aren't physically checked beyond the bio-data page (though it varies), only electronically and then it's stamped

Comment: The fact that the non-visa national passports are stamped, necessarily means that the officer is accessing the other pages of the document beyond just the bio-data page. For low-risk travellers, not every page will be scrutinised in detail - but the whole document will be riffled through in any case: just sufficient for the officer to get a picture of the travel history. They will also need to find a place to put the stamp :)

Comment: What I've seen in many cases is them only browsing to find an available space for the endorsement after doing their checks. Anyways, fair enough, I've undone the edit

Comment: I usually also give them a list of languages I speak if their native language isn't among them.

Comment: from my very limited experience, and although I try to be polite and smiling with everybody, the typical non-smiling and non-speaking immigration officer is really not an incentive to be kind. What I usually read in their eyes is "No, this morning will not be good cause I'm here and would so much prefer be anywhere else"

Comment: As edited, we Canadians don't fit either of those two categories.  We need no visa (normally), nor are we EU/Swiss nationals.

Comment: Jim - for non-visa nationals such as Canadians, you may present the passport open at the bio-daya page - or as a closed booklet. It makes no difference to the officer, as she will have to flick through all the pages anyway.

Comment: I usually say hello. More often than not, I receive no response at all. (I have no experience with UK passport control.)

Comment: +1. I think that should be the accepted answer since it comes from an authoritative figure. I always say a simple "hello" because I am polite and they are human beings. I extend this to any staff in the airport I came close to and make eye contact. I let passport control officers initiate small talk if they want/need it. I got variable reactions: officers in Guam were very friendly, while officers in Hong Kong and Macau just ignored me and checked my passport without any word. But greetings were never frowned upon.

Answer (score 39):

There's no strict rule.

If they say hello (good morning / good evening / etc.) when you walk up, say hello back.
If they say "Hi, how are you today?" then answer them.
If they just say "passport please", just hand over your passport.
If they don't say anything, just quietly hand over your passport.
I usually say thank you when they hand everything back at the end but I'm sure if you don't they won't be particularly put out by it.

From the point of view of efficiency, make sure you know what documentation they will require at that particular point and have anything they might need to see from you to hand. It may just be passport, it may also be a landing card that you have to fill out before you get to the desk, they may want to know your flight number, details of your return itinerary, or ask about where you are staying.

You don't need to offer any of this documentation until it is asked for, but if you have all your travel related documentation in one easily-accessible location in your hand luggage, you will save yourself and them time if they need to ask you for anything else. From the point of view of somebody who is sitting there for however many hours one of their shifts is, I'm sure what they mainly want is for you to hand them what they need with minimal fuss and go on your way once they've ticked whatever boxes need ticking.

Comment: What they want is *a short queue of people*, which keeps the general level of stress and aggravation low. Small talk wastes time and *increases* the queue length - unless there happens to be no queue when you arrive at the control point. But even then, the officer doesn't know if the "customer" (i.e. you!) is in a hurry to get to some place else, so he/she is unlikely to take up your time on small talk - unless there is a problem with your documentation, and he/she is waiting for someone else to come but doesn't want to tell *you* there is a problem yet.

Comment: For most of the world, yes. For US passport control though, be prepared for what sounds like like small talk but is actually power tripping. Exact conversation: "What's the purpose for your visit?" "I've got business meetings at Ford." "How long for?" "We should be finished by Friday, but it might go into next week." ***"WHY DON'T YOU KNOW!?"***

Comment: Once I arrived in a country other than my own -- my BF was standing between me and the passport control officer, so I gave my passport to my BF, and he gave it to the officer.  Who then turned to me an said, *"but where is your passport?"* to which I replied, *"in your hand".*  We're still laughing about that one.

Comment: @Graham. Agreed. For my colleague it went like this: “ Why are you here?”, “I’m here to do some installation work for BT.” “BT? Like British Telecom? This is America, there ain’t no British Telecom here son.” Tossers.

Comment: @Graham Mine once purposely turned the fingerprint scan off to check for suspicious responses. I was... mildly agitated after a 14 hour flight...

Comment: Yeah, arriving to South Africa is way nicer. I was greeted with "Hello, how are you?" from the border official and asked him to repeat it because I couldn't believe that this would be his first question :)

Comment: @Graham Well, I'd say experiences vary. In my experience the US passport control officers have generally been either very direct and businesslike, or friendly and engaging (in a way that gets them the information they need to collect). I've never encountered one who was rude or pushy. Of course, I am a US citizen; I'm not sure if things are more likely to be otherwise for non-citizens.

Comment: @DavidZ My experiences with the CBP are fairly positive as well (Swedish passport, VWP visitor)

Comment: @DavidZ I've never had a rude or pushy CBP officer, either (British citizen) and they usually open with something like "Hi, how are you?"

Comment: Arriving in the US; they ask rather aggressively "Why are you here?" "Business" "What is your business?" "I'm here to attend a conference on ballistics." "What's that?" "Er... rocket science" "OMG she's a rocket scientist! Look everybody, a rocket scientist!"

Comment: When I arrive in the US I have the feeling they suspect I am here illegally and have no other wish than to remain. I need a way to convey that I'm sure it's very nice here but actually when my business is done I can't wait to go home to civilisation.

Comment: @Darren That was completely by design. Somebody who is telling the truth: "Well BT owns a fiber going from Britain to the US that terminates in New York and I am here to install..." Somebody who is lying: "Uhhh.... Well.... I guess I'm here for..."

Comment: @RedSonja To some extent, I think you've been unlucky in your interactions with the US officers, on two counts: 1) Some people would consider "Business" a snarky or evasive answer to "Why are you here?", when the answer is "I'm here to attend a conference." 2) "Rocket science" is the butt of many jokes in the US, as something so esoteric or complicated that the common man won't understand or care about it. See, for example, the common idiom "It's not rocket science", about something easy to do.

Comment: @Owl The following trip, I did out-literal them.  "Do you have any nuts, seeds, or grains?" "Just these." <produces bag of peanuts with absolute deadpan face>  I could see the guy pause as he mentally checked what he could do me for, but I held the poker face and he clearly decided it was more trouble to argue over something which was literally true.

Answer (score 26):

I personally (nearly) always say hello (just hello) while handing over my passport, even if they don't say anything. I'll often try to use the local version if I know it. Once finished, usually a thank you and/or goodbye. Beyond that, it's up to them.

I wouldn't go into any "how are you today" or anything like that unless they initiate it. They see hundreds or thousands of people, they're often not really in the mood for a chat, though this depends a bit on the culture, a bit like when you're greeted in a store: in the US for instance, you will annoyingly be asked how you are today by every single person within 10 feet, and some (but not all) US CBP officers will do the same. In most other places it won't go further than hello (if that) unless they have questions.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with US culture it should also be noted that the response to being asked how you are in a professional context, or by a stranger, is usually "fine, thanks," regardless of how you actually are.

Comment: For the record that's true in the UK, too, though you won't be asked as often or as enthusiastically.

Comment: this depends on bit on the culture -> this depends a bit on the culture. (I don't have enough rep to edit, and the edit is less than 6 chars.)

Answer (score 17):

There's no particular etiquette. I usually say "Hello" or "Hi" when when I hand over my passport: it's a friendly thing to do and, in non-English-speaking countries, it hints that I'd like them to speak English to me. (Though they'd probably guess that from my British passport.)

Comment: The language negotiating hint is a very good point. (I do much the same thing, but make a point of saying "Good morning/afternoon", because just "Hello" is phonetically close to its equivalent in German, French, and probably more.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Though one hardly uses "Allô" in French other than on the phone xD

Comment: My most frequent border crossings are between US and Québec.  Lots of anglophones and francophones going in each direction.  The Canadian border officer usually initiates with a bilingual “Bonjour/hello.”  The one you give back is the language they will proceed in.

Answer (score 9):

Depends on the country. In the UK and US, for example, the officers greet me (and/or me them) whereas in former Yugoslavia, Albania, Moldova, Turkey and Georgia, they never say a word to me. The same is true IME when entering/exiting Singapore at Woodlands.

In the Schengen Area it varies.

(for what it's worth, I'm on a Swedish passport/ID card)

Answer (score 1):

The last time I faced a passport control officer was at Barajas Airport (Madrid/Spain).
It was my second time there and I felt SO happy that my smile was covering my whole face as I got off the plane and walked thru the customs hall.

When the agent noded me to walk five steps towards him and present him my passport I greet him smiling and he smiled me back with sympathy as he asked me the purpose of my trip.

We are all human. They have an awful job: looking for delinquent and terrorist among tons of happy tourists or angry business travelers. I can understand that they do not smile a lot at work, but you can show them a nice smile and say "Hi, good morning". It will not harm anyone. ;)

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is hard for officers to say **hi** and **bye** to people in the row. Imagine! You are going to say it all through the working shift—non-stop!

If you say any greeting to the officer, it means you are somehow expecting or forcing him/her to reply the greeting, which is inconvenient!

I recommend to just smile instead of “hi” and move your head as bye with a little bit squeeze on your lips (something like a close smile). This means you care and appreciate but you do not expect a reply!

Comment: When I buy groceries, the person at the checkout has no difficulty in saying hello to each customer, all through the working shift, non-stop. Why would it be any different for immigration officers?

Comment: @DavidRicherby the person helping you at the grocery store sees a few dozen customers an hour, not a few hundred. Small difference, but significant.

Comment: @jwenting A few hundred people an hour is a person every ten seconds (interperting "a few" as "three"). I'm pretty sure they don't see more than, say, 100 an hour in the home passports line, and probably not more than, say, 20 an hour in the foreign passports. So, OK, more than the grocery store for home passports, but not _much_ more.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I don’t know if you travel alot or not. But if you do, I would like to ask: Do you usually get response from visa officers?

Comment: @Zich I travel internationall a couplefew times a year. In the UK and US, they usually say hello back; in other countries they usually at least acknowledge/smile/nod; some places they barely seem to react at all. (Actually, last time I went to Spain, the border guard was too busy talking to his pal about football to even look at me.) But I've never had anything happen that made me think saying hello was in any way bad.

Comment: @DavidRicherby it's not bad, don't get me wrong. But don't expect a response. They'd "hello to you too" themselves hoarse well before the end of their shift :)

Comment: @jwenting Why are you continuing to push this line? I’m sorry, but it’s nonsense. In the UK, they _always_ greet me and they’re not hoarse. In the US, they always talk to me for a couple of minutes, so “Hello” makes no significant difference. In call centres, people talk for basically their whole shift and they don’t go hoarse. Sure, in some countries they won’t say a word but that has nothing to do with protecting their voices.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Ok! Lets be exact then. In case we are dealing with busy officers just a smile would be fine but if they have couple of minute to talk to you! You may be able to socialize, like “Hey Watsup?! Do you think Taylor Swift should feat Beyonce? 

Answer (score -3):

Simple cordiality is polite, but don't start spilling your guts or recounting your biography. These people are not your friend. They can send you to prison or to your death. Their notes may follow you around for life.

They are no more interested in being your friend than bar staff. They will also be trained to detect attempts at misdirection, and they may misunderstand a colloquialism as profanity or blasphemy, whichever is worse.

..and the longer the queue is held up, the more likely someone behind you will cause trouble.  I went through T5 at Heathrow from Amsterdam late December last year, a three hour queue. Some idiot abused an officer and the officer walked off the job, leaving three officers for a thousand odd passengers. Some of which had problems with their entry cards, very trying for these people. Be nice, it's their workplace, but don't waste their time. They may have a KPI (key performance indicator) or SLA(Service Level Agreement) to meet.

Comment: The question didn't ask "should I tell the officer my whole life story, it asked about saying "hello." In what countries can a border control officer send you to your death? Also, I'm not sure about the relevance of your last paragraph ... why do I care about their KPI or SLA?

Comment: Singapore, Indonesia, Myanmar, Malaysia, and any number of other countries still have the death penalty and do exercise it. You care about their KPI or SLA because you may be a "secret shopper" and be expecting a 6 hour interview to result from your contact. These people are watching you, and someone is watching them. Check the wrong box, say the wrong word, not understand the "take" protocols, and you could become very inconvenienced.

Comment: Yeah, sure, so does the US. Does Singapore execute people that lie at the border or something? But I'm not a "secret shopper," and this question isn't about being a "secret shopper," it's about being a regular traveler. Why should I, as a tourist or business visitor care about a KPI or SLA?