# Can I enter Russia 10 hours before visa validity?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, russia

My visa validation starts from Aug 25th and, unfortunately, my flight to Moscow arrives on 24th Aug.

Can I wait there in airport until my visa is valid to enter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to enter Russia by train 1-1.5 hours before the visa validity period starts?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71950/is-it-possible-to-enter-russia-by-train-1-1-5-hours-before-the-visa-validity-per)

Comment: Hm, not really a full dupe, since OP could argue that they spend the 15 or so hours in the international arrivals area before immigration, couldn’t they?

Comment: Which airport will you arrive at? I dont think there is a room before immigration border where you could spend 10 hours.

Answer (score 4):

The airline will not let you board the flight, because if they do, they'll have to send you back and pay a fine to the Russian government for transporting you without a valid visa.

So you Need to re-book your ticket.

Comment: I'd call the airline and ask them if there's any way to kill 10 hours airside after departing the plane. Very likely they'll say "no no no, we really need to change your travel date" and with any luck, be willing to waive some fees.